# Xpath for div tag exclude span tag and return text

Tags: xml, xpath, scrapy

I need xpath for below HTML code

```
  <div itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemscope="" itemprop="jobLocation">
  <div class="aiDetailJobInfoLabel aiDetailJobInfoLocation">Location: </div>
  <div class="aiDetailJobInfo aiDetailJobInfoLocation">
     <span itemprop="addressLocality">Topeka</span>
      , KS
      <span itemprop="postalCode">66607</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this HTML code i need output as
     Topeka , KS

It should not include 66607

I tried with this code, but its giving empty

```
 >>> response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="jobLocation"]/div[@class="aiDetailJobInfo aiDetailJobInfoLocation"][not(child::span[@itemprop="postalCode"])]//text()').extract()
```

If i write below code, its giving

> > > response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="jobLocation"]/div[@class="aiDetailJobInfo aiDetailJobInfoLocation"]//text()').extract()

```
output: Topeka, KS, 66607
```

Please help me out.

FYI:
xpath will be having with div text() which exclude postal code, so that remaining div and span text is returned. Sometime postalCode is not present in this div tag. So if it present, skip it, if not return whole div tag text.

Answer (score 0):

Here I shared 2 piece of code. you can take what ever you need.

Try this:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="aiDetailJobInfo aiDetailJobInfoLocation"]//text()').re(r'[ .a-zA-Z]\w+')



response.xpath('//div[@class="aiDetailJobInfo aiDetailJobInfoLocation"]//text()').re(r'[a-zA-Z]+')


response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="jobLocation"]/div[@class="aiDetailJobInfo aiDetailJobInfoLocation"]//text()').extract()[1:3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Both it returns only Topeka, But i need Topeka, KS. It should not include postal code. Remaining whatever text inside div tag, everything should be return.

Comment: Nice one.! Cant we handled by xpath only instead of regex. ? I am planning to do with xpath only. Something like, extract div tag text without span postalCode tag.

Comment: you may use slicing to  get the result like

Comment: response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="jobLocation"]/div[@class="aiDetailJobInfo aiDetailJobInfoLocation"]//text()').extract()[1:3]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you essentially want the concatenation of all the text node descendants of the target `div` *except* those under the `postalCode` property.  The relevant set of text nodes would be found by an XPath like

```
//div[@itemprop="jobLocation"]/div[@class="aiDetailJobInfo aiDetailJobInfoLocation"]
   //text()[not(parent::span[@itemProp="postalCode"])]
```

If you `.extract` this XPath you'll get a list of strings (one for each text node) that you can concatenate together at the Python level.